# In Microsoft Access, Why is there a Duplicate "add Tables" box when creating Queries?

Tags: ms-access, user-interface, ms-office

I've used Microsoft Access for over 20 years now as a database designer, and programmer.  When our company moved to Office 365 I was excited to see what new options and features the design team at Microsoft had created for us.

To my surprise, when I went to create a query, a task I've done thousands of times, I was perplexed to see a second "Add Tables" Box pop up automatically, when there was already a perfectly good "Add Tables" box.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3f2L5.png)

I've looked through the documentation such as it is, and I've looked through the menus.  I cannot see a checkbox to get rid of this extra window, nor a way to keep it from popping up.  Even if you close it, every time go to create a new Query, IT'S BACK!  Like some sort of bad penny, or overzealous designer.

Thanks in Advance.

-Brian P.

---

This text had to go here, since the "comments" are only a few characters;

I'm just surprised most people (Developers) aren't having more problems in this regard.  You assert that: **People keep the nav pane collapsed to make more room** - to which I say, Since Monitors are larger than they were say 15 or 20 years ago, that may have been the case. However, for the last 10 years, I divide my screen up like this:

1. left column, (OUTSIDE of Access) I have the property box / add
   available fields inside access,
2. nav pane, which allows me to drag and drop fields, queries, into my
   forms, reports or queries - as well as open Modules if I need
   something in there
3. Finally room for forms/Reports that float (I've never undestood the
   tabbed look except that eases the transition for excel users)

[Picture of my Layout of Access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFmoi.png)

This new right pain (oops, Pane) doesn't allow me access to Modules.  Neither does it allow me to drag fields into a form, so, the only thing it seems to do is allow you to add fields to queries.  If it either of these things then I could ditch the Nav Pane and use this new one, except for the fact that seems to appear on the right, and not the left where it seems more intuitive to add objects from.

Thanks for your fine discussion on this matter

Answer (score 1):

Well, on the left side - that's not a add tables feature - it is the nav pane - you can drag + drop from that nav pane, but it is NOT a add tables feature.

The right side? yes, that a is new panel in 2021.

Try right click in your query builder area - I believe there is a option to show that right side new panel. Try to see if it toggles for you.

Comment: Yes, right click qnd "add table" is one of the options that I see.  It's already being shown though, right when I create the Query.  

I'm not trying to show this window though, I'm trying to get it to go away.  I don't want it to come up.  I already have a window that lets me add all the tables I would even need.  I don't need a second window to do that.  

Am I not being clear in what I'm hoping to accomplish?    It's really a pain in the arse, because even if I close it, the next query I create opens the Add tables box back up, and I have to close it again.

Comment: but the navpane is NOT ONLY for adding tables. Most people don't use drag + drop from nav pane to the query builder (since it often collapsed to get more room then right???). (but, yes, you can - most in the past used right click add table)., I had noted the right click context menu in case that option "toggles" the right pane  (apparently it does not - I had hoped it does/did). So yes, I grasp the goal is to not show the right pane by default -  I don't know if it is possible right now.  Most people have more wide space then vertical space - so not a issue for most.